# Display value from mysql table as 'selected' in a select input field

Tags: php

In my form I have a select input field that is populated with data from mysql db. I am trying to display the selected value in this select input field from table `academy` where `status` is either `active` or `inactive`.  In the example below the academy has a status of `inactive` but when trying to echo the selected value it displays incorrectly; `active` instead of `inactive`. Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/select_test.php).

```
<form action="" method="post">
//Read results from database
$db_select1  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name, 
       a.academy_id,
       a.status
FROM academy a
WHERE a.academy_id = 15
");
if (!$db_select1) return false;
    if (!$db_select1->execute()) return false;
    $results1 = $db_select1->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results1)) return false;
    foreach ($results1 as $value1){
          $result1 .= "<strong>Academy Name: </strong>".$value1['name']."</br>";
          $result1 .= "<strong>Academy ID: </strong>".$value1['academy_id']."</br>";
          $status = $value1["status"]; 
    }

    echo $result1;


echo $resutl1;
?>
 <strong>Academy Status:</strong>
        <?php
                //Populate select input
                $table_name2 = "academy";
                $column_name2 = "status";

                echo "<select name=\"$column_name2\"><option>Select one</option>";
                $sql1 = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table_name2.' WHERE field="'.$column_name2.'"';
                $row1 = $db_con->query($sql1)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $selected = '';
                foreach(explode("','",substr($row1['Type'],6,-2)) as $option) {
                    if ($status == $option) // $status is the status of your record from the database
                       $selected = "selected";
                    echo "<option value='$option'" . $selected. ">$option</option>";
                }
                echo "</select></br>";   
        ?>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
 </form>
```

*Stored Values in academy table:*

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+
| academy_id |       name        | status   |
+------------+-------------------+----------+
|       15   | Brown High School | Inactive |
+------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: `var_dump($status, $option);` on each foreach iteration and see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SELECTED=SELECTED`

```
foreach(explode("','",substr($row1['Type'],6,-2)) as $option) {
if ($status == $option){
      $selected = "selected=selected";

}else{

      $selected=''
}

      echo "<option value='$option'" . $selected. ">$option</option>";
}
```